# ASP.NET MVC Last visited data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to show Last Ten Pages Visited Cookie with asp.net mvc?

Comment: Could you be more precise ?

Comment: I have several pages, each page has a search in order to unite all the tracks on one side who previously visited last and present them to the new page..

Comment: Ok, but what is your problem ? Your question is too large, you need to precise if your problem is to recover, to store or to display the information, for example. Otherwise, we could only give you a general answer.

Comment: I do not know how can I save the URL address and display it. I need a code...

Comment: How it can be done by using a cookie? An example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the url for each accessed page, you can use the `Application_BeginRequest` method of the global.asax, which will be called whatever the page accessed.

Example :

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentUrl = this.Context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    // Store the currentUrl to your database, for example
}
```

Comment: Tnx, this is it. Now how can I displayed this url ?

Comment: Once stored (in a database or other), you can display it by using a basic html link (`<a>` tag).

Comment: I understand. How can I store url in database (code example)? And how show list of Url's, because I need last ten using code ...Sorry, Im new on asp.net mvc..

Comment: I think you should first follow a basic tutorial on ASP.NET MVC. I cannot give you all the code for what you want to do...

Comment: I agree, thank you for help...